# How to submit jobs across multiple partitions at the same time (Slurm)

Tags: slurm

After I submit a job to node/partition `cn430` today, I find that the node is keeping obsessed,

[image]

After the previous job finished, my job still didn't get running due to priority. Then I noticed that all of these jobs have the same prefix, namely `4988443`, which is ahead of my job id `4988560`.

It seems that the user has submitted about 1000 jobs together with the same priority across multiple partitions,

[image]
[image]

I am wondering how to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstoff, `cn430` really looks like a node rather than a partition. The partition to which it belongs seems to be named `shared-gp`.

What you see is a [job array](https://slurm.schedmd.com/job_array.html). It is a way to submit a large number of jobs that only differ in a specific parameter. Each job in the array is scheduled independently, so if you do not request a specific node (e.g. with `-w`or `--nodelist`), Slurm will broadcast them to the nodes that are available.

Note that the job priorities will decay overtime if faishare is being implemented so the jobs that are currently pending will have their priority decrease because of those currently running.